# Load my local image like a map in c# include tile loading, zoom, define simple overlay objects like pins

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, maps

I want to load my own map in an image formats (bmp or png or jpg or any picture format) to a winform. and it should has zoom feature and i want to show it on multiple screen (for example : extended monitor)

The second part of my question is about put overlay objects (may be only a clickable image) like google maps pins.

if any other infos are needed, ask for them in comments

Tnx dear experts

Comment: Soooo where is the question here?

Comment: how to implement these use cases? what is the best practice? this is my question

Comment: He, I need to build something similar coul you please help me with some starting point? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Gilbert, sorry, I don't even remember for which project I was working on this. It was like 9 years ago! :D

Answer (score 0):

Search "bing map tile system" on the net

Look at the site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

This is how BING & Google Maps are implemented, no doubt the best practice, search also for Bing Map Tile Server, Microsoft publishes guidelines for creating your own tile server these are the guidelines for using images from Bing Map on your local server in your case I think you will have your own images....